# net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED al realizar petición POST a backend .NET Framework

Tags: javascript, .net

Tengo un backend en .NET Framework el cual esta debidamente configurado con el nuget de Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors. He publicado este Api en un servidor con IIS y quedo como HTTP sin embargo ese no es el problema ya que tengo también otros con HTTP y no me dan ese problema pero seguramente es porque los clientes son Xamarin forms y no js. El tema es que me devuelve un net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED cada vez que hago un llamado .
A raíz de esto decidí publicar el mismo Api pero en un app service de Azure y entonces ahí si es una URL con HTTPS y entonces ahí si me responde bien. A que se debe esto? Es algo meramente de el certificado SSL o que?? Adjunto el código del cliente Javascript:

```
async function crearConfiguracion(url, raw) {
    try {

        var myHeaders = new Headers();
        myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
        myHeaders.append("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        var requestOptions = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: myHeaders,
            body: raw,
            redirect: 'follow'
        };


        await fetch(`${url}api/email/Configuracion`, requestOptions)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(result => {
                console.log(`result  ${result}`);
                if (result == `realizado`) {
                    Swal.fire({
                        title: 'Listo!',
                        text: `Configuración exitosa`,
                        icon: 'success',
                        confirmButtonText: 'Ok'
                    });
                } else {
                    Swal.fire({
                        title: 'Error!',
                        text: `Lo sentimos, la configuración no se pudo realizar por problemas de comunicación`,
                        icon: 'error',
                        confirmButtonText: 'Ok'
                    });
                }
            })
            .catch(error => console.log('error', error));

    } catch (error) {
        await Swal.fire({
            title: 'Error!',
            text: `Lo sentimos: ${error}`,
            icon: 'error',
            confirmButtonText: 'Ok'
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Alguna vez se me presentó un problema similar, donde ocupaba realizar peticiones desde mi Frontend en (Vercel) a un servidor sin SSL, cada petición que hacía se me rechazaba, para ello para solucionarlo realicé lo siguiente:

Principalmente no utilizaba la Api Fetch de Js, utilizaba la librería Axios para realizar peticiones y otra librería llamada https.

Yo te recomendaría utilizar algún certificado SSL o TLS en tus servicios.

El código siguiente es solamente un ejemplo.

```js
import axios from "axios";
import https from "https";

const agent = new https.Agent({
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
});

const getClient = async () => {
  const response = await axios.get('<END POINT>', { 
    httpsAgent: agent
  })
  
  console.log(response);
}
```